# Ionic3 keep keyboard after send message

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, keyboard, textarea, ionic3

I have the following html in Ionic3 page to implement a chat:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea placeholder="Write your message" [(ngModel)]="newMessage"></ion-textarea>
    <button ion-button clear item-right icon-only (click)="sendMessage()">
      <ion-icon name="paper-plane"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-item>
```

I'd like to keep device keyboard shown untill the user press device "back button" or outside the ion-textarea element. I've tried using ionFocus and ionBlur events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put this in you config.xml for IOS Device

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

Or in Android you need to preventDefault like this on function call:

```
 (mousedown)="$event.preventDefault()"
```

Comment: I've already tried it. It didn't work, the keyboard closes after I click on sendMessage button. I'm running the app in an Android device. Maybe <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" /> only works in IOS?

Comment: Yes this preference  is for IOS device, you use android ?

Comment: add this to your send button maybe :

(mousedown)="$event.preventDefault(); sendMessage($event)"
i hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes, android device

Comment: When you send your message, the e.preventDefault(); will prevent automatic change like keyboard going down

Comment: It works! I only had to add (mousedown)="$event.preventDefault()" inside html element and the keyboard remains opened. Thanks!

Comment: Done! But I have < 15 reputation... :(

Comment: @LeoR. Could you please update the answer to add `(mousedown)="$event.preventDefault()"` when using Android? It may help other SO users facing the same issue :)